# Getting issue with heremap multiple pickup and multiple drop api

Tags: reactjs, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I am using multiple pickup api with prams as suggested by heremap docs:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/findpickups.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&start=waypoint0;50.115620,8.631210;pickup:GRAPEFRUIS,value:1000&departure=2020-11-14T07:30:00&driverCost=20&restTimes=disabled&end=waypoint7;50.132540,8.649280;drop:GRAPEFRUITS,value:1000&destination0=waypoint1;50.118578,8.636551;drop:APPLES,value:30&destination1=waypoint2;50.122540,8.631070;pickup:BANANAS&destination2=waypoint3;50.128920,8.629830;drop:BANANAS,value:30&destination3=waypoint4;50.118654,8.619956;pickup:APPLES&destination4=waypoint5;50.123998,8.640626;drop:PEACHES,value:50&destination5=waypoint6;50.130299,8.613031;pickup:PEACHES&apiKey={key}
```

**drop for GRAPEFRUIT is defined but getting error message:** No drop-off point defined for payload GRAPEFRUIS,value:1000

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your url:

1. There is a typo (GRAPEFRUIS)
2. pickup doesn't have a value field (see https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/api-reference-type-waypoint.html)
3. "pickup only allowed at optional way points"

So if you change

```
start=waypoint0;50.115620,8.631210;pickup:GRAPEFRUIS,value:1000
```

to

```
start=waypoint0;50.115620,8.631210
```

and

```
end=waypoint7;50.132540,8.649280;drop:GRAPEFRUITS,value:1000
```

to

```
end=waypoint7;50.132540,8.649280
```

then this url will work:

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/findpickups.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&start=waypoint0;50.115620,8.631210&departure=2020-11-14T07:30:00&driverCost=20&restTimes=disabled&end=waypoint7;50.132540,8.649280&destination0=waypoint1;50.118578,8.636551;drop:APPLES,value:30&destination1=waypoint2;50.122540,8.631070;pickup:BANANAS&destination2=waypoint3;50.128920,8.629830;drop:BANANAS,value:30&destination3=waypoint4;50.118654,8.619956;pickup:APPLES&destination4=waypoint5;50.123998,8.640626;drop:PEACHES,value:50&destination5=waypoint6;50.130299,8.613031;pickup:PEACHES&apiKey={key}
```

Comment: why my fulfilledConstraints is empty then?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. They are empty even when I execute their example - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-pickup.html

Comment: okay thanks for your help really appreciated :-)

Comment: one more issue i am getting with sequencing not able to see all the waypoints in result please check 

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/findpickups.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-11-14T07:30:00&driverCost=20&restTimes=disabled&start=waypoint0;31.10111,77.15165&destination1=waypoint1;29.62592,76.97787;pickup:PEACH&destination2=waypoint2;22.73483,75.89035;drop:PEACH,value:10&end=waypoint3;31.64393,76.64354&apiKey={api_key}